# Roles is not saving in user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I was following this [video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association) from railscast for adding a roles for users. It is possible to have multiple roles as admin, author. When I save or update new registration form role field is not saved in database. All other fields save properly. I do not get any error also.

when I write this in console  `User.with_role("admin")` I get `{:conditions=>"roles_mask & 1 > 0 "}`

I am using rails 4 and devise gem. I implemented according to the tutorial and below is my code

**application_controller.rb**

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit({ roles: [] }, :display_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end
```

**user.rb**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :posts

  scope :with_role, lambda { |role| {:conditions => "roles_mask & #{2**ROLES.index(role.to_s)} > 0 "} }

  ROLES = %w[admin author]

  def roles=(roles)
    self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r)}.sum
  end

  def roles
    ROLES.reject { |r| ((roles_mask || 0 ) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero? }
  end

  def role_symbols
    roles.map(&:to_sym)
  end

  def role?(role)
    roles.include? role.to_s
  end
```

**registration/new.html.erb**

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br/>
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <% if @minimum_password_length %>
          <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
      <% end %><br/>
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br/>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :roles %>
      <% for role in User::ROLES %>
          <%= check_box_tag "user[roles][]", role, @user.roles.include?(role) %>
          <%= h role.humanize %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user[roles][]" %>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Why roles are not being saved and how can I make it work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Devise, but are you whitelisting the role attribute(s) via strong parameters in what I'm assuming is the users controller?

Comment: There is no controller for users. So I am whitelisting from application controller

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Instead of a simple `check_box_tag` use what forms in *ROR* provides you:

   ```
   <%= f.check_box :role %>
   ```

   *Note: assuming **:role** is the field that contains the role of a specific user signing up.*
2. In your application controller, inside `def configured_permitted_parameters`, try to permite the parameter **:role**, not the options of role you got. It'd be something like this:

   ```
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:role, :display_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
   ```
3. I would suggest you to use a select tag instead of checkbox, so you make your user don't miss or forget to specify his role. But this is not mandatory, it would only be better if you expect to add roles in your available roles to select. With this way, in your form, you use the same space with two or three or any quantity of roles. The code as follow: *in your form*

   ```
   <%= f.select :role, options_for_select(get_roles), {} %>
   ```

   *this in your **app/helpers/users_helper.rb**.*

   ```
   module UsersHelper
       def get_roles
           # here something that returns an array or a matrix of roles
           # return ['admin','author]
           # or 
           # return [['admin',1],['author',2]]
       end
   end
   ```

I assumed in the schema of your user model you have a column for the role.